# Where can I find the definitions of binary trees and the algorithms associated with them in isabelle?

Tags: binary-tree, isabelle

Where can I find the definition of a binary tree and the algorithms associated with binary trees in Isabelle?

I am a beginner in Isabelle and, therefore, I am looking for new learning materials. Recently, I was trying to find the definition of a binary tree and the algorithms on binary trees in Isabelle, but, unfortunately, my attempt failed. Where can I find them? Thank you for your help in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Binary trees are defined in HOL-Library (`~~/src/HOL/Library/Tree.thy`). Some algorithms on them (i.e. implementations of data structures such as AVL trees with them) are defined in HOL-Data_Structures (`~~/src/HOL/Data_Structures/`).

Both of these are in the Isabelle distribution. You can import them by writing e.g. `"Data_Structures.AVL_Set"` or `"HOL-Library.Tree"` (the quotation marks are required when there's a dash in the name).